# Select models with highest counts through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hi I have a two models `report` and `report_day_count`

`report` has many `report_day_counts` and `report_day_count` belongs to `report` and has an attribute called `count`.

I'd like to sort the reports by the sum of their report_day_count counts, but I'm not sure how to do this with active record.

I've tried:

```
    report.joins(:report_day_counts).sum(:count)
```

but that just sums all the counts together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to the following:

```
Report
  .left_outer_joins(:report_day_counts)
  .group('reports.id')
  .select('reports.*, SUM(report_day_counts.count) AS report_day_counts_sum')
  .order('report_day_counts_sum DESC')
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this

`Report.joins(:report_day_count).group('report.id').order('SUM(report_day_counts.count')`